# How to configure Asterisk realtime with mysql properly?

Tags: asterisk

I currently have over 1k realtime users setup on a MySQL server(only 10-20 users will register simulatneously) for Asterisk.  The problem is the sip is not registering evertime.  Sometimes I get 'registration timeout'. Is there a setup guide or a setting which I need to configure in order to have >99% successful registrations?

Comment: You question can't be answered. Default configuration of ARI can handle millions users without any issues. So you have debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never faced the issue as I have fewer users.

But according to the aterisk documentation:

If you have problems with your network connection going up and down (e.g. an unreliable cable connection) and you keep losing your **sip registry**, you may want to add **registerattempts** and **registertimeout** settings to the general section above the register definitions.
 Setting `registerattempts=0` will force Asterisk to attempt to reregister until it can (the default is 10 tries).

**registertimeout** sets the length of time in seconds between registration attempts (the default is 20 seconds).

*About achieving **99**% success:*
I think you have to study your system and apply setting to the above variables accordingly (*dynamically*). I suggest using **Markovian models** like [mm1 simulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/1_queue)  if your system is not complicated.